# Map is getting empty outside use effect where I set its value

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am fetching data from api, then mapping it. When I try to print values inside it it prints correctly.
But when I try to print same after sometime in other function it shows empty.
This is the only 2 places where I have used my map nowhere else.

```
const catmap = new Map();

  useEffect(() => {
    // fetch categories
    getCategories().then((res) => {
      setCategories(res.data);
   

      res.data.map(
        (c) => {
          catmap.set(c._id, c.name);
          
        }

      );
      console.log("mycate len", catmap);  //correctly map the values
      console.log("mycate len", catmap.size);  //and shows it size

    }); 

  }, []);
```

```
useEffect(() => {
   let currentUrlParams = new URLSearchParams(window.location.search);

    console.log("mycate len", catmap); 
   console.log("mycate len", catmap.size); //Here It shows empty and zero size

  
 }, [categoryIds]);
```

Comment: It seems a [stale clousure](https://dmitripavlutin.com/react-hooks-stale-closures/#3-state-closure-in-useeffect) issue. Could you upload your code somewhere and explain the steps to replicate it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it's important to understand how state is handled in React. Any value that is subject to change, and for which changes need to be tracked, within the lifecycle of the components, should be wrapped in state.

So in React, you can use `useState`.

```
const catmap = new Map();
```

should become

```
const [catmap, setCatmap]= useState(new Map());
```

Now you have a value `catmap` that you can use throughout your component. And a setter `setCatmap` that you can use to update the value.

Your current effect is mapping over the response data and using it to mutate the map, this works within the scope which is why logging in the effect seems to have updated the map, but React won't be able to track any updates.

But now you have a setter you can use that.

So can do

```
const nextMap = res.data.map((c) => {
  catmap.set(c._id, c.name);
});
setCatmap(nextMap)
```

but references should also be updated for the changes to be tracked by React so you should also create a new map

```
setCatmap(new Map(nextMap))
```

Or if you want to update from current state, for example if there were already items in the map

```
setCatmap(
  (current) =>
    new Map([...current.entries(), ...res.data.map((c) => [c._id, c.name])]),
);
```